# How come I can initialize a UIView without parameters, but its documentation does not have an empty initializer?

Tags: ios, swift

```
let view = UIView()
```

Why does this compile without an error when the only documented `UIView` initializer is `init(frame: CGRect)`?

Specifically, I am trying to write a new class that inherits from `UIView`, but this code throws an error:

```
class SquadHorizontalScrollViewCell: UIView {

    init(var: FIRDataSnapshot){
        super.init()
....
```

It says it must call a designated initializer.

Comment: It behaves like init(frame: CGRect) has a default argument: init(frame: CGRect = .zero). Maybe it is the case?

Answer (score 5):

`UIView` inherits from `UIResponder` which inherits from `NSObject`.

The `NSObject.init()` [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418641-init) is accessible on `UIView`, but not on subclasses of `NSObject` which replace this designated initializer.

Let's consider an example.

```
class A: NSObject { 
    init(_ string: String) { } 
}
```

This leads to a compiler error for `let a = A()` - missing argument #1 for initializer because this initializer replaces the designated `init()` initializer for `NSObject` in the subclass.

You just need to define the initializer of the subclass as a `convenience` initializer:

```
class A: NSObject { 
    convenience init(_ string: String) { 
        self.init() // Convenience initializers must call a designated initializer.
    } 
}
```

`let a = A()` now compiles.

`UIView` can also compile with other designated initializers defined in the subclass, since its designated initializer is not known at compile time. As per the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622488-init), if instantiating programmatically, `init(frame:)` is the designated initializer, otherwise `init()` is the designated initializer. This means that `UIView` inherits the `NSObject` designated initializer rather than replacing it as in the above example.

In your example:

```
class SquadHorizontalScrollViewCell: UIView {

    init(var: FIRDataSnapshot){
        super.init()
```

We see that the designated initializer is `init(frame: CGRect)`, so you have to call this designated initializer instead.

Answer (score 2):

A designated initializer should call its superclass designated initializer.

In this case `super.init()` is the designated initializer of `NSObject` not `UIView`.
It would be UIView's responsibility to call UIResponder init ,I guess it has no designated initializer, hence UIView will call `Super.init` in its `init(frame:CGrect)` initializer. check "Initializer Delegation"

for why `let x = UIView()` is ok , its because of this

> Unlike subclasses in Objective-C, Swift subclasses do not inherit
>   their superclass initializers by default. Swift’s approach prevents a
>   situation in which a simple initializer from a superclass is inherited
>   by a more specialized subclass and is used to create a new instance of
>   the subclass that is not fully or correctly initialized. (Apple)

since UIView is objective c class it still can do it. but you won't be able to call SquadHorizontalScrollViewCell() unless you did not provide any initializer or you overrides the designated initializer of the superclass (UIView)

---

Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) for more info

Answer (score 1):

At a certain point your view will need to be init with something, that is why the compilation is complaining, because it cannot find how to start the initialisation of your custom view. Because at the end, a view will be init from a xib (`init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`), or from a frame ( `init(frame: CGFrame)`). So here, the easiest way is to call `super.init(frame: CGRectZero)` at least in your custom init method.

```
init (var: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)   
}
// This method below is always needed when you want to override your init method
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

but you'll still need to set the size of your frame etc.

Comment: this does not answer the OP's main question, why `let view = UIView()` works when there is no empty initializer documented for UIView

Answer (score 1):

For `UIView` `init(frame: CGRect)` is default initializer. You must call it after initialize your instance variable. If you take view from `NIB` then  `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is called instead of `init(frame: CGRect)`. So in that case you have to initialize your instance variable in `awakeFromNib()` method. In this case your code should be like this:

```
class SquadHorizontalScrollViewCell: UIView {

    init(firDataSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){

        // intialize your instance variable
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero) // set your expected frame. For demo I have set `CGRectZero`

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

For more info you can check this link https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice if you create your own `UIView` subclass and only override `init(frame:)` with a log statement, then instantiate this new class using just `init()`, your `init(frame:)` is actually called with a zero-sized frame. So the designated initializer is still getting called.

Comment: That's exactly what happens, but why it works that way? I can't find any initializers with .zero default frame value or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add another aspect to the other answers. If you implement a subclass of UIView in Swift and do not provide the `init(frame:)` initialiser, an exception will be thrown at runtime:

```
Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:)' for class 'x_swiftlang_01Tests.U'
```

When you add that initialiser like shown below, you will get an interesting log output:

```
func testU() throws {
    class U: UIView {
        let s: String
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            return nil
        }
        // Without init(frame:) an exception is thrown:
        // "Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:)' for class 'x_swiftlang_01Tests.U'"
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            self.s = "framed"
            super.init(frame: frame)
        }
        init(s: String) {
            self.s = s
            super.init()
            print("\(#function): init:s=\(s)")
        }
        deinit { print("\(#function): deinit:s=\(s)") }
    }
    let u = U(s: "u")
}
```

Output:

```
init(s:): init:s=u
deinit: deinit:s=framed
```

Basically two initialisers will be called and the second one will override whatever the first one did set.
Don't call `super.init()`, but `super.init(frame: .zero)` to correct that.