# Why does calling init() calls init(frame: CGRect)?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

When I have a custom `UIView` with overridden init like this:

```
class ContainerView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setup() {
    }
}
```

Why am I able to initialize the view with a simple `init` like this and the `setup()` method is called?

```
let view = CustomView()
```

I would expect it to NOT be called when I'm calling the simple NSObject `init()` and not the `init(frame: CGRect)`?

How is the `frame` parameter passed then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952355/how-come-i-can-initialize-a-uiview-without-parameters-but-its-documentation-do may be helpful

Comment: didnt find before, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `CustomView()` is using an inherited initializer for `NSObject`. This implicitly calls `UIView`'s designated initializer, `init(frame:)` with `.zero`. Since you've overriden that initializer, your override is called and thus the `setup()` method is called too.

You can see this by printing out the `frame` parameter in your initializer; you will get a `.zero` rect.